# using Selenium.PhantomJS.WebDriver with .Net Core

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, .net-core

The NuGet package [Selenium.PhantomJS.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.PhantomJS/), on building the project, it copies PhantomJS.exe to the ***bin*** folder. With classic .Net it works very well.

The problem is that with .NetCore this doesn't work. I could add the file to the solution directly, specifying to ***copyOnBuild*** but I would like to avoid it. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? Just stumbled upon the same problem.

Comment: Not yet buddy. In the end I went for some manual workaround, but not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two workaround came to my mind;

If you have chance to use such a custom tool like **CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies**, you can try below in your .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Second option:

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)packages\Selenium.PhantomJS.WebDriver.{version}\tools\phantomjs.exe" "$(TargetDir)"
```

You can put this command in the postbuild. I'vent tried, however these might work.